# Program hits an infinite loop in the printPoly() function

Tags: c, infinite-loop

This program which is supposed to read 2 polynomials from the user and then print out the sum; is hitting an infinite loop once both the polynomials have been entered.

- To store a polynomial, Structure is being used with a forward declaration of *plink which would point to the next term (node)
- The readPoly() function is supposed to read a polynomial based on the number of terms provided.
- Each polynomial is a circular linked list and the resultant polynomial is also supposed to be stored in a circular linked list
- The Compare() function compares the exponents and adds 2 terms and attaches then to the resultant polynomial in case the exponents are same, else they are just attached to the resulatant polynomial

Each of the Polynomials have a header node which helps in traversing the list in a circular manner.

Since the header node does not contain any data "related" to the polynomial, their exponent fields have been initialized with -1

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"

#define SIZE 10

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
struct poly
{
int exp;
float coef;
struct poly *plink;
};

typedef struct poly PNODE;

PNODE* getNode()
{
PNODE *ptr= (PNODE*)malloc(sizeof(PNODE));
if(ptr==NULL)
{
    printf("\nNo Memory\n");
    return;
}
return ptr;
}
    void readPoly(PNODE *phead, int n)
    {
        int i, ex;
        float co;
        PNODE *temp,*newnode;
        temp=phead;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            printf("\nEnter the EXPONENT and COEFFICIENT for term %d\n",i);
            scanf("%d%f",&ex,&co);

            newnode=getNode();

            newnode->exp=ex;
            newnode->coef=co;

            temp->plink=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
        }
     temp->plink=phead;
     return;
    }

    void printPoly(PNODE* phead)
    {
        PNODE *i=phead;
        for(i=phead->plink;i->plink!=phead;i=phead->plink)
            {
                printf("%2f(x^%d)+",i->coef,i->exp);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

int compare(int a, int b)
    {
        if(a>b)
        {
           return 1;
        }
         if(b>a)
        {
         return -1;
        }
       if(a==b)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

void attach(int exp, float coef, PNODE **add)
{
    PNODE *temp;
    temp=getNode();

temp->exp=exp;
temp->coef=coef;

(*add)->plink=temp;
*add=temp;
    return;
}

PNODE* addPoly(PNODE *phead1, PNODE *phead2)
{
PNODE *startA, *res, *tempres;
int done= FALSE;
float sum= 0.0;

startA=phead1;

phead1=phead1->plink;
phead2=phead2->plink;

res=getNode();
res->exp=-1;
tempres=res;

do
{
    switch(compare(phead1->exp,phead2->exp))
    {
         case 1: attach(phead1->coef,phead1->exp,&tempres);
                phead1=phead1->plink;
                break;
         case -1: attach(phead2->coef,phead2->exp,&tempres);
                phead2=phead2->plink;
                break;
         case 0: if(startA==phead1)
                        {
                            done=TRUE;
                        }
                else
                {
                    sum=phead1->coef+phead2->coef;
                    if(sum)
                    {
                        attach(sum,phead1->coef,&tempres);
                    }
                   phead1=phead1->plink;
                   phead2=phead2->plink;
                }
                break;

    }
}while(!done);
tempres->plink=res;
return res;
}
int main()
{
int n1, n2;
PNODE *phead1, *phead2,*result;

phead1=(PNODE*)malloc(sizeof(PNODE));
phead2=(PNODE*)malloc(sizeof(PNODE));

phead1->exp=-1;
phead2->exp=-1;

phead1->plink=phead1;
phead2->plink=phead2;

printf("\nEnter the number of terms in Polynomial 1\n");
scanf("%d",&n1);
readPoly(phead1,n1);
printf("\nEnter the number of terms in Polynomial 2\n");
scanf("%d",&n2);
readPoly(phead2,n2);

printf("The first Polynomial is \n");
printPoly(phead1);
printf("The second Polynomial is \n");
printPoly(phead2);

printf("Result is\n");
result=addPoly(phead1,phead2);
printPoly(result);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not again. Check the return value of `scanf`

Comment: Step through the code where you add nodes, line by line, and keep track of the `plink` member of all the nodes involved (as well as the nodes themselves). Keep track of the list you build on paper, each time a node or a link is changed, draw up the new list on the paper.

Comment: @EdHeal the printPoly() function hits the Infinite loop how do I check the return value of scanf there? It's just supposed to print the polynomials

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did, the printPoly() function is somehow entering the infinite loop even though it is logically correct

Comment: Just check it when scanf is called. If it fails it stores rubbish

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=phead->plink;i->plink!=phead;i=phead->plink)
```

`i` is always assigned the same value, so the loop never ends. It should be  `i = i->plink` to move to the next node.

Comment: Nope! still doesn't help

Comment: @PrateekDavePhoenix This is definitely a problem in your code, so don't say it doesn't help. You may have other issues as well.

Comment: With all due respect, I tried that already, it still hits an infinite loop as soon as it's done accepting the terms of both polynomials and then, has to print them

Comment: @PrateekDavePhoenix Then you have additional issues. Sounds like you need to do some debugging.